# new Basecamp API add/update subscribers to calendar event

Tags: api, events, calendar, basecamp, subscriber

Is it possible to add or update people (subscribers) in a calendar event in Basecamp new API?

In a documentation https://github.com/basecamp/bcx-api/blob/master/sections/calendar_events.md are only these parameters:

```
{
  "summary": "My all-day event spanning two days",
  "description": "Details to follow",
  "all_day": true,
  "starts_at": "2012-03-28",
  "ends_at": "2012-03-30"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not currently, sorry.  I'll pass on the suggestion for you - thanks!